# Invoke GCP Cloud Run Service from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-iam

I understand based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-servicehttps://) documentation that you need to assign the Invoker role to the calling service on the service that is being called. I have an App Engine service trying to invoke a Cloud Run service that requires authenticated requests.

I have followed the documentation and have assigned the Cloud Run Invoker role to the default App Engine service account and am using an axios interceptor to attach the auth header to requests made from my App Engine Service with this code.

```js
const { GoogleAuth } = require("google-auth-library");

let client;
async function  getBearer(serviceBaseURL) {
// where serviceBaseURL is the URL of the service being called from this app engine service
    const auth = new GoogleAuth();
    try {
      if (!client)
        client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(serviceBaseURL);
      const clientHeaders = await client.getRequestHeaders();
      console.log(clientHeaders);
      // this logs `Bearer dy4UbC...`
      return clientHeaders["Authorization"];
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      throw Error("could not create an identity token: ", err);
    }
  }
```

The axios interceptor is written like this:

```js
authApiClient.interceptors.request.use(
  async (opts) => {
    const token = await getBearer(config.networking.auth_service_base);

    opts.headers['Authorization'] = token;
    return opts;
  },
  (err) => Promise.reject(err)
);
```

For some reason I am still getting a 401 unauthorized error when trying to invoke my service.

Is there any additional steps I need to be taking beyond assigning the right roles, and then reaching out to the metadata server to get the proper bearer token?

Comment: What does this log **console.log(clientHeaders["Authorization"];);** Do not show the entire token just the first few chars. The function should be returning "Bearer <ID_TOKEN>". Make sure you are creating the HTTP Authorization header correctly with that value if you are not later in your code using **client**. Edit your question and show how you are using the HTTP Authorization header and making a request.

Comment: What is the base URL that you use? Can you share the pattern of this URL?

Comment: @JohnHanley I have edited the question to show I am using the interceptor

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the URL is the URL of the service I am looking to hit with structure : https://service-name-dsfg6sd84-ue.a.run.app

Comment: Your code looks OK. That means that the service account that App Engine is assigned does not have the Invoker role on the Cloud Run service. Go to the Cloud Run service in the Google Cloud Console GUI and verify that the service account is bound to Cloud Run with the invoker role.

Comment: 1. Which account are you using? Please confirm from the gcloud auth list command. The account with the asterisk must be authorized in Cloud Run. You can also run gcloud config config-helper and double check the core/account property.
2. Also can you run it with curl -v to see the headers? 
3. How did you add the cloud run invoker role to the default service account, using gcloud/GUI?
If done through gcloud, please make sure gcloud version is at least 243.0.0 by "gcloud --version'' and "gcloud components update" to update if gcloud is too old.